# jquery cookie vertical toggle menu

Tags: jquery, cookies, menu, toggle

I have built a nice vertical menu that toggles with jquery and I need to be able to save the state, subject to what category the visitor is seeing.

I have built a fiddle to show what i have:

http://jsfiddle.net/FbCDV/15/

...looks great!! :)

...so if a user clicks to another category or product/page I need the menu to stay open.

...the jquery to work what i have so far is:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#category-menu #categories button', function(){

    if(jQuery(this).parent().hasClass('expandable')) {
        jQuery(this).html('+');
        jQuery(this).siblings('ul').stop(true,true).css('display','block').slideUp(200, 'linear', function(){
            jQuery(this).parent().toggleClass('expandable');
        });
    } else {
        jQuery(this).html('-');
        jQuery(this).siblings('ul').stop(true,true).css('display','none').slideDown(200, 'linear');
        jQuery(this).parent().toggleClass('expandable');
    };

});
```

...i did some hunting around the interwebbie world and see that I could maybe use the jquery cookie plugin.

...i have played around with it but I'm getting stuck! :(

...the actual site the menu is on is a dynamic PHP driven site.

...any guidance would be awesome! :)

Comment: OK...i have managed to get a new fiddle working, this time by matching URL, no cookies needed, this works...but i can;t work out how to close the menu "+" blocks :(

Comment: ...this is my new fiddle:

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/J8HnC/

Comment: ...as we can see, i am matching the url, which works great...but lost with the logic for getting the thing to close, toggle properly.